# Variadic templates: choose the tuple element type that has a proper method

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

I have a class like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
class Evaluator
{
public:
    template <typename... Types>
    Evaluator(Types... args)
    {
        list = std::make_tuple(args...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool Evaluate(const T& input)
    {
        // based on a specific input type T, here I want to call
        // Evaluate(input) for a specific element in the tuple. i.e. the
        // element that has method Evaluate, for which Evaluate(input) compiles 
        return std::get<0>(list).Evaluate(input);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Types...> list;

};
```

**Update** The function could return false for instances that don't have proper "Evaluate(input) -> bool" function and is evaluated for all matching with bool result ||

Comment: Your constructor shouldn't be a template itself.

Comment: Is `std::get<0>` an example or do you really want to iterate over each element and call `Evaluate` (given they have the method)?

Comment: What if more elements match?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I want to call evaluate on all that have a matching method ideally.

Comment: @Ghita Does `Evaluate` return a `bool`? And what do you want to return if more types match, &&'ed or ||'d result?

Comment: @jrok It has to call all of them(side efects) and return result bool as ||

Comment: I don't understand how you want to return a value (bool) and yet call `Evaluate` on **every** element of the tuple...

Comment: I'd do this in two steps.  First, write code that does something for each `tuple` element.  Then, write code that only calls Evaluate iff it compiles, and otherwise does nothing.  To test the first one, try it with streaming to `std::cout` a heterogeneous `std::tuple` of `int`, `double` and `char const*`.  What compiler are you using?  What should `Evaluate` return if none compile?  What should it return if more than one compile?

Comment: I think Boost Mpl has both copy_if and for_each. Combine for great profit

Comment: `bool result ||` ??? You mean you want to return `true` iff any of them return `true`?  Do you want to short-circuit as `||` implies?

Comment: @Yakk no short circuit because evaluation is done for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need a metafunction which can tell us whether the expression `declval<T>().Evaluate(input)` makes sense for a given type `T`.

We can use SFINAE and decltype in order to do so:

```
template<class ... Arguments>
struct CanEvaluate
{
    template<class T, class Enable = void>
    struct eval : std::false_type {};

    template<class T>
    struct eval<T,
        decltype( void( std::declval<T>().Evaluate(std::declval<Arguments>() ... ) ) ) > : std::true_type {};
};
```

Now we can write a single class `MultiEvaluateFromTuple`.

```
template<class TupleType, class ... InputTypes>
struct MultiEvaluateFromTuple
{
private:
    template<int I,int S,class Dummy = void>
    struct CheckEvaluate : CanEvaluate<InputTypes...>::template eval<typename std::tuple_element<I,TupleType>::type> {};

    //We need this because we can't instantiate std::tuple_element<S,TupleType>
    template<int S> struct CheckEvaluate<S,S> : std::false_type {};

    // Forward to the next element
    template<int I,int S, class Enabler = void>
    struct Impl {
        static bool eval(const TupleType & r, const InputTypes & ... input) {
            return Impl<I+1,S>::eval(r,input...);
        }
    };

    // Call T::Evalute()
    template<int I,int S>
    struct Impl<I,S, typename std::enable_if<CheckEvaluate<I,S>::value>::type> {

        static bool eval(const TupleType & r, const InputTypes & ... input) {
            bool Lhs = std::get<I>(r).Evaluate(input...);
            bool Rhs = Impl<I+1,S>::eval(r,input...);
            return Lhs || Rhs;
        }
    };

    //! Termination
    template<int S>
    struct Impl<S,S> {
        static bool eval(const TupleType & r, const InputTypes & ... input) {
            return false;
        }
    };

public:
    static bool eval(const TupleType & r,const InputTypes & ... input) {
        return Impl<0, std::tuple_size<TupleType>::value>::eval(r,input...);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
return MultiEvaluateFromTuple<std::tuple<Types...>,T>::eval(list,input);
```

This will call `Evaluate` for all the types `T` in `Types` for which `CanEvaluate<InputType>::eval<T>::value == true`, and return the || of the results.

Comment: Just got the chance to try it out quickly, but for some reason call to // Call T::Evalute() is never made. And I also tried modifying the CanEvaluate::eval to be always true_type

Comment: @Ghita That' strange. I tested this code before posting (G++-4.8.1 here)

Comment: @Ghita It is probably releated to constness issue. I passed TupleType by const reference, while you need non-const. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: If I remove const as you said it works with gcc (not with vs11, the only version with variadics support, CTP november 2012 - here compiles but does not call proper functions). I'm wondering why const has the effect there though...

Comment: @Ghita http://ideone.com/VbVcZr . Seems that VS11 fails to instantiate the first specialization of Impl when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
// Unspecialized form, when the current element doesn't match. Tries the next one.
template <typename Tuple, int I, typename Argument, typename = void>
struct CallEvaluate : CallEvaluate<Tuple, I+1, Argument> {};

// Termination case, when the end of the tuple was reached. Has no operator () and will
// cause a compilation error.
template <typename Tuple, typename Argument>
struct CallEvaluate<Tuple, std::tuple_size<I>::value, Argument> {}; // no type fits

// Termination case, when the call std::get<I>(list).Evaluate(input) is valid.
template <typename Tuple, int I, typename Argument>
struct CallEvaluate<Tuple, I, Argument,
                    decltype(void(
                      std::declval<typename std::tuple_element<Tuple, I>::type>()
                        .Evaluate(std::declval<const Argument&>())))> {
   bool operator ()(const Tuple& list, const Argument& input) const {
     return std::get<I>(list).Evaluate(input);
   }
};


// Use:
CallEvaluate<decltype(list), 0, T>()(list, input);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it compile. how do I instantiate the CallEvaluate object ?

Comment: Probably I should mention I'm using vs11 November CTP here, that has variadic templates support.

Comment: I don't know if this will actually compile, it was just a start of a solution that I came up with. It still needs debugging. And I'm not sure if VS11's extended SFINAE support is good enough either. (In any case, why not use VS 2012 Express? It's free and far less buggy than the CTP. If you want a CTP, use the VS 2013 one.)

Comment: it's not the VS11 CTP, it's the only update to VS11 that has support for variadics :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Here's what I think is the solution:

```
template <typename... Types>
class Evaluator
{
private:
    std::tuple<Types...> list;

    template <typename T>
    struct has_evaluator
    {
        typedef char yes;
        typedef char no[2];

        template <typename C, C>
        struct S;

        template <typename U>
        yes& check(S<bool T::*, &T::Evaluate>*);

        template <typename U>
        no& check(...);

        static const bool value = sizeof(check<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char);
    };
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Evaluator(Args&&... args) : list(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    { }

    template <typename T,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                  has_evaluator<typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(list)>::type>::value>::type>
    auto Evaluate(const T& input) -> decltype(std::get<0>(list).Evaluate(input), bool())
    {
        return std::get<0>(list).Evaluate(input);
    }
};
```

Comment: this one seems to try to call only for element 0, under certain conditions. I have to iterate

Comment: @Ghita But you're trying to return a value from the function... So which value do I return? You can't iterate and return multiple values at once.

Comment: you can return the value you want, just need to iterate. sbabbi tried to make || there, unfortunately that doesn't work